# Possible to combine position_jitter with position_dodge?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've become quite fond of boxplots in which jittered points are overlain over the boxplots to represent the actual data, as below:

```
set.seed(7)
l1 <- gl(3, 1, length=102, labels=letters[1:3])
l2 <- gl(2, 51, length=102, labels=LETTERS[1:2]) # Will use this later
y <- runif(102)
d <- data.frame(l1, l2, y)

ggplot(d, aes(x=l1, y=y)) + 
  geom_point(position=position_jitter(width=0.2), alpha=0.5) +
  geom_boxplot(fill=NA)
```

[image]

(These are particularly helpful when there are very different numbers of data points in each box.)

I'd like to use this technique when I am also (implicitly) using `position_dodge` to separate boxplots by a second variable, e.g.

```
ggplot(d, aes(x=l1, y=y, colour=l2)) + 
  geom_point(position=position_jitter(width=0.2), alpha=0.5) +
  geom_boxplot(fill=NA)
```

[image]

However, I can't figure out how to dodge the points by the `colour` variable (here, `l2`) and also jitter them.

Comment: You have already received some nice answers, so this comment is more of a small background. When I struggled with a similar problem myself a while ago, I stumbled over [this presentation](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/42707925/ggplot2/ggplot2slides.pdf). Check the example on p. 19-20. The combination of `geom_jitter` and `dodge` apparently worked in a previous version of `ggplot`. Not anymore...

Comment: I also really like showing the actual points along with my boxplots, but I tend to use dot plots.  They avoid the jittering problem and can give a nice sense of the shape of the data in each group.  You still have to work out the appropriate `dodge` in `geom_dotplot` in a case like this, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an approach that manually performs the jittering and dodging.

```
# a plot with no dodging or jittering of the points 
dp <- ggplot(d, aes(x=l1, y=y, colour=l2)) + 
  geom_point(alpha=0.5) +
  geom_boxplot(fill=NA)

# build the plot for rendering
foo <- ggplot_build(dp)
# now replace the 'x' values in the data for layer 1 (unjittered and un-dodged points)
# with the appropriately dodged and jittered points
foo$data[[1]][['x']] <- jitter(foo$data[[2]][['x']][foo$data[[1]][['group']]],amount = 0.2)
# now draw the plot (need to explicitly load grid package)
library(grid)
grid.draw(ggplot_gtable(foo))
# note the following works without explicitly loading grid
plot(ggplot_gtable(foo))
```

[image]

Comment: I really liked the `foo$data[[2]][['x']][foo$data[[1]][['group']]]` part. I was close to start a big `merge`-by-group-operation. +1!

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you'll like it, but I've never found a way around this except to produce your own x values for the points. In this case:

```
d$l1.num <- as.numeric(d$l1)
d$l2.num <- (as.numeric(d$l2)/3)-(1/3 + 1/6)
d$x <- d$l1.num + d$l2.num

ggplot(d, aes(l1, y, colour = l2)) + geom_boxplot(fill = NA) +
  geom_point(aes(x = x), position = position_jitter(width = 0.15), alpha = 0.5) + theme_bw()
```

[image]

It's certainly a long way from ideal, but becomes routine pretty quickly. If anyone has an alternative solution, I'd be very happy!

Answer (score 3):

The new position_jitterdodge() works for this. However, it requires the fill aesthetic to tell it how to group points, so you have to specify a manual fill to get uncolored boxes:

```
ggplot(d, aes(x=l1, y=y, colour=l2, fill=l2)) + 
  geom_point(position=position_jitterdodge(width=0.2), alpha=0.5) +
  geom_boxplot() + scale_fill_manual(values=rep('white', length(unique(l2))))
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm using a newer version of ggplot2 (ggplot2_2.2.1.9000) and I was struggling to find an answer that worked for a similar plot of my own. @John Didon's answer produced an error for me; `Error in position_jitterdodge(width = 0.2) : unused argument (width = 0.2)`.  I had previous code that worked with geom_jitter that stopped working after downloading the newer version of ggplot2. This is how I solved it  below - **minimal-fuss code...**.

```
ggplot(d, aes(x=l1, y=y, colour=l2, fill=l2)) + 
  geom_point(position = position_jitterdodge(dodge.width = 1, 
                                             jitter.width = 0.5), alpha=0.5) +
  geom_boxplot(position = position_dodge(width = 1), fill = NA)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another  option would be to use facets:

```
set.seed(7)
   l1 <- gl(3, 1, length=102, labels=letters[1:3])
   l2 <- gl(2, 51, length=102, labels=LETTERS[1:2]) # Will use this later
   y <- runif(102)
   d <- data.frame(l1, l2, y)

   ggplot(d, aes(x=l1, y=y, colour=l2)) + 
     geom_point(position=position_jitter(width=0.2), alpha=0.5) +
     geom_boxplot(fill=NA) +
     facet_grid(.~l2) +
     theme_bw()
```

Sorry, don´t have enough points to post the resulting graph.