# Mapping hexcolor codes in a variable for stacked bar plots in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, geom-bar, color-codes

Data frame "df" has 4 fields. Seeking to plot a stacked bar plot of x= "wellid", y="Freq" (aggregates to 1 for all wellid), filled using the "property" code (nlith <- nlevels(df$property = 26)
Want to assign a specific hexadecimal colour code for each "property". The codes are created and stored as the fourth field "hexcolor" in df

Few records from "df" are below:

```
        property     wellid Freq hexcolor
    225      BIR 009410X 0.048951049  #7F55D4
    226      BIR 009910X 0.060150376  #7F55D4
    227      BIR 010810X 0.000000000  #7F55D4
    228      BIR 011010X 0.093959732  #7F55D4
    299      BJR 065010X 0.000000000  #7F7FD4
    300      BJR 065610X 0.006451613  #7F7FD4
    301      BKP 006610X 0.198473282  #7FD455
    302      BKP 009010X 0.187050360  #7FD455
    303      BKP 009110X 0.069767442  #7FD455
```

The "property" - "hexcolor" reference is as in this data frame:

```
         property hexcolor
    1         CIR  #D455D4
    9         CJR  #D47FD4
    10        CJQ  #D47F7F
    11        CKQ  #D4D47F
    23        BKP  #7FD455
    24        BKQ  #7FD47F
    25        BJQ  #7F7F7F
    53        AJP  #557F55
    54        AKP  #55D455
    64        AJQ  #557F7F
    85        BJP  #7F7F55
    103       BIQ  #7F557F
    116       AJR  #557FD4
    118       AIR  #5555D4
    121       BIR  #7F55D4
    234       CKP  #D4D455
    244       AIQ  #55557F
    285       CJP  #D47F55
    327       AKQ  #55D47F
    505       BJR  #7F7FD4
    537       CIQ  #D4557F
    1901       JQ  #007F7F
    1909       IR  #0055D4
    2363        A  #550000
    2365        B  #70000F
    2387           #000000
```

ggplot geom_bar() code tried produced correct graph - BUT with default colour table:

```
    plt <- ggplot(df, aes(x= wellid, y= Freq, fill= property)) + geom_bar( stat = "identity")
    plt + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, size = 10))
```

[image: Stacked Bar Relative Frequency Plot with Default Colour Table for "property"]
Need guidance to colour code this picture using the "hexcolor" scheme in the data frame "df".  Tried a bit without success!!

Comment: You need to tell it what colors to use with `scale_fill_*`, making sure they're not factors, by adding `+ scale_fill_manual(values = as.character(setNames(df_hexcolor_reference$hexcolor, df_hexcolor_reference$property)))` where `df_hexcolor_reference` is the lookup data.frame.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to alistaire for pointing to solution:

## guidance taken from :: [scale_fill_manual based on another factor in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19068040/scale-fill-manual-based-on-another-factor-in-ggplot2)

```
    plt <- ggplot(df, aes(x= wellid, y= Freq, fill= property)) + geom_bar( stat = "identity") + 
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, size = 10))
    plt + scale_fill_manual(values = as.character(fourcol$hexcolor))
```

Produced the desired answer[image: scale_fill_manual based on another factor in ggplot2]