# Overlap measurement points on a grouped geom_boxplot() using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

my data looks like this

```
d1 <- data.frame(BAI2013 = rnorm(30),
                 class = rep(letters[1:3], 10),
                 treatment = rep(c("elevated","ambient"),15))
```

I plot the following boxplot, including the points of the measurements and removing the outliers:

```
p<- (ggplot(d1, aes(x = class, y = BAI2013)))

p + geom_boxplot(outlier.size = 0, aes(fill=factor(treatment))) + 
  geom_point(aes(color = factor(treatment)))
```

[image]

The problem is that, as you can see, the points drawn in the x axis corresponding to `class`,  whereas I want the points overlapping each box instead of the center of each group.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are happy for them to be centred, you can use `position_dodge()`:

```
p + geom_boxplot(outlier.size = 0, aes(fill=factor(treatment))) + 
  geom_point(aes(color = factor(treatment)), position = position_dodge(width = 0.75))
```

[image]

If you want them jittered, [it gets trickier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19018568/possible-to-combine-position-jitter-with-position-dodge), but it's possible

Answer (score 0):

You might try starting with

```
p<- (ggplot(d1, aes(x = interaction(class, treatment), y = BAI2013)))
```

You'll then have to think of what you want the labels/ordering to actually look like, but everything will be lined up.